# Why aren't my images loading from my JSON file?

Tags: java, json, image, gson

I was trying to load images from a JSON file using GSON, and after reading multiple threads on StackOverflow, I found that the best solution was to store to URL in the JSON file and then load it into an image. The problem is, my application is failing to load these URLs into an image, and I have no idea why. For example, when I go into debug mode: [Debug Mode Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8fGf.png)

It shows that images are null.

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
    "shoes": [
        {
            "shoeName": "Shoe",
            "shoePrice": "120",
            "brand": "Shoe",
            "typeOfShoes": "Running",
            "style": "Cool",
            "colors": [
                "Blue",
                "Green",
                "Pink"
            ],
            "sizes": [
                "W5/M3.5",
                "W5.5/M4"
            ],
            "description": "The Shoe SE features sleek lines and a sheer upper that combine classic Air Max elements into a lightweight, comfortable and versatile icon. Together with its smart toe-down profile and extra lift, the shoe offers an ever-bigger expression..",
            "shipping": "0",
            "tax": "0",
            "subtotal": "0",
            "review": "4.5",
            "totalRaffles": "80",
            "imageURLs": ["https://www.nike.com/t/vaporfly-4-flyknit-running-shoe-v7G3FB"],
            "isSold": "false"
        },
        {
            "shoeName": "Empty Shoe",
            "shoePrice": "0",
            "brand": "null",
            "typeOfShoes": "null",
            "style": "null",
            "colors": ["null"
            ],
            "sizes": ["null"
            ],
            "description": "null",
            "shipping": "0",
            "tax": "0",
            "subtotal": "0",
            "review": "0",
            "totalRaffles": "0",
            "imageURLs": ["https://www.nike.com/t/vaporfly-4-flyknit-running-shoe-v7G3FB"],
            "isSold": "false"
        },
        {
            "shoeName": "Empty Shoe1",
            "shoePrice": "0",
            "brand": "null",
            "typeOfShoes": "null",
            "style": "null",
            "colors": ["null"
            ],
            "sizes": ["null"
            ],
            "description": "null",
            "shipping": "0",
            "tax": "0",
            "subtotal": "0",
            "review": "0",
            "totalRaffles": "0",
            "imageURLs": ["https://www.nike.com/t/vaporfly-4-flyknit-running-shoe-v7G3FB"],
            "isSold": "false"
        }
    ]

    }
```

The ReadJSON.java is a class for reading the JSON file.

**ReadJSON.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.pulsebeat02.main.gui.Shoe;
import com.pulsebeat02.main.gui.windows.StartingWindow;

public class ReadJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        parseJSON();

    }

    public static void parseJSON() {

        String cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        File f = new File(cwd + "/shoes.json");

        String str = null;
        try {
            str = readFile(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Type dataType = (new TypeToken<Shoes>() {
        }).getType();

        Shoes shoeList = gson.fromJson(str, dataType);

        List<Shoe> shoes = shoeList.getShoes();

        Shoe [] shoesFinal = new Shoe[shoes.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < shoesFinal.length; i++) {

            shoesFinal[i] = shoes.get(i);

        }

        StartingWindow.shoesInGui = shoesFinal;

        System.out.println(shoeList);
        System.out.println("Ran");

    }

    public static String readFile(File file) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
    }

}
```

Here is the Shoe class used to define the shoe object:

**Shoe.java**

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Shoe {

    public int shoePrice;
    public int shipping;
    public int tax;
    public int subtotal;
    public int totalRaffles;

    public double review;

    public String shoeName;
    public String style;
    public String typeOfShoes;
    public String brand;

    public String[] imageURLs;

    public Image[] images;

    public String description;
    public String[] colors;
    public String[] sizes;

    public boolean isSold;

    public Shoe(int shoePrice, int shipping, int tax, int subtotal, double review,

            int totalRaffles,

            String shoeName, String style, String typeOfShoes, String brand,

            String[] imageURLs,

            String description, String[] colors, String[] sizes,

            boolean isSold) {

        this.shoePrice = shoePrice;
        this.shipping = shipping;
        this.tax = tax;
        this.subtotal = subtotal;
        this.review = review;
        this.totalRaffles = totalRaffles;
        this.sizes = sizes;
        this.shoeName = shoeName;
        this.style = style;
        this.typeOfShoes = typeOfShoes;

        Image[] imagesFinal = new Image[imageURLs.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {

            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(imageURLs[i]);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Image c = null;
            try {
                c = ImageIO.read(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imagesFinal[i] = c;

        }

        this.images = imagesFinal;
        this.description = description;
        this.colors = colors;
        this.isSold = isSold;
        this.brand = brand;

    }

    public Shoe(String shoePrice2, String shipping2, String tax2, String subTotal2, String review2,
            String totalRaffles2, String shoeName2, String style2, String typeOfShoes2, String brand2,
            List<String> images2, String description2, List<String> color, List<String> sizes2, String isSold2) {

        this.shoePrice = Integer.parseInt(shoePrice2);
        this.shipping = Integer.parseInt(shipping2);
        this.tax = Integer.parseInt(tax2);
        this.subtotal = Integer.parseInt(subTotal2);
        this.review = Double.parseDouble(review2);
        this.totalRaffles = Integer.parseInt(totalRaffles2);

        this.shoeName = shoeName2;
        this.style = style2;
        this.typeOfShoes = typeOfShoes2;
        this.brand = brand2;

        this.images = loadImage((String[]) images2.toArray());
        this.description = description2;
        this.colors = (String[]) color.toArray();
        this.sizes = (String[]) sizes2.toArray();
        this.isSold = Boolean.getBoolean(isSold2);

    }

    public Shoe (Shoe s) {

        super();

    }

    public static Shoe[] toArray(List<Shoe> list) {

        Shoe[] shoes = new Shoe[list.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            shoes[i] = list.get(i);

        }

        return shoes;

    }

    public static Image[] loadImage(String[] imageURLs) {

        Image[] images = new Image[imageURLs.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {

            Image image = null;
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new URL(imageURLs[i]));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            images[i] = image;

        }

        return images;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URLS you have in the sample are not image URLs but generic web URLS.
Here is working code sample with correct & absolute image URL ( execute this URL on browser ):

```
Image image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_864_v1/f_auto,b_rgb:f5f5f5/ds8ojj70wtpthbzadaft/air-max-dia-se-shoe-WCG8t5.jpg"));
    System.out.println("Image read");
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see. The URLs didn't lead to the file itself. Thank you so much!